# Need for NoSQL Android Cache

Tags: android, mongodb, kotlin, nosql, android-room

I am running several MongoDb based API's implemented with Spring Data

My problem is to have a Android Cache Db that can handle Documents, especially Documents with Embedded Documents seamlessly!

MongoDb seem to have a solution (MongoDb Realm) BUT it is connected to a Paid for hosted Db

As a sample with Fake data received as JSON from the API call to the Back-End could look like this

```
{
  "detail": "Page 1 of 1",
  "count": 1,
  "page": 1,
  "results": [
    {
      "prospectId": "5cb2e9424274072ec4bb419c",
      "name": "Bill",
      "lastName": "Gates",
      "phone": "0108101081",
      "email": "gates.william@gmail.com",
      "company": {
        "companyId": "60847dc8ba7e6a4ae0fa5f93",
        "name": "Microsoft",
        "email": "info@Microsoft.com",
        "address": {
          "addressId": "5cb2e9424274072ec4bb4199",
          "label": "Home",
          "number": "1",
          "street": "Microsoft Way",
          "timestamp": 1631087921460
        },
        "timestamp": 1631087921855
      },
      "address": {
        "addressId": "5cb2e9424274072ec4bb4199",
        "label": "Home",
        "number": "1",
        "street": "Microsoft Way",
        "timestamp": 1631087921460
      },
      "timestamp": 1631087922537
    }
  ]
}
```

**Prospect Class**

```kotlin
class Prospect {
    
    @Id
    var prospectId: String? = null
    var name: String? = null
    var lastName: String? = null
    var phone: String? = null
    var email: String? = null
    
    @DBRef
    var company: Company? = null
    
    @DBRef
    var address: Address? = null
    var timestamp: Long = nowToLongUTC()
}
```

**My Company**

```kotlin
class Company {
    
    @Id
    var companyId: String? = null
    var name: String? = null
    var email: String? = null
    
    @DBRef
    var address: Address? = null
    var timestamp: Long? = null
}
```

**My Address**

```kotlin
class Address {
    @Id
    var addressId: String? = null
    var label: String? = null
    var number: String? = null
    var street: String? = null
    var timestamp: Long = nowToLongUTC()
}
```

It is generated from a classes that includes `@dbRef Company` and `@dbRef Address`
Company also include `@dbRef Address`

Both the Prospect and the Company includes an Address, combined it has Document in Document in Document structure

Which is quite a natural reference document in noSql type documents

**I need to have an Android Cache that understands noSql (MongoDb) and can natively handle that document embedded in document embedded in document**,

Room fails galactically! being a SQL and suffers doing it properly.  Using room's `@Embedded` notation helps for one level of embedded document but the next level need to be using a TypeConverter.  That is how SQL fails me.

Comment: There's nothing built into android to do this, and this site isn't for library recommendations.  However having done this myself I have a strong recommendation-  pay up.  This is extremely difficult work to do and keeping caches in sync is a full time engineering job.  Its worth the money to have someone else do it.  There is no way in hell the cost of the engineer's time writing it is more than the cost of buying any solution you find.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can take a look at the Nitrite database [here](https://github.com/nitrite/nitrite-java). Nitrite is an open source nosql embedded document store written in Java which is ideal for Android or Java desktop applications. Fortunately for you, it supports mongodb like api.

In your particular use case, there are two options here.

1. You remove the `@DBRef` annotations (nitrite does not support db reference) and insert the `Prospect` object into a nitrite object repository with all its embedded object.

```kotlin
class Prospect {
    @Id
    var prospectId: String? = null
    var name: String? = null
    var lastName: String? = null
    var phone: String? = null
    var email: String? = null
    var company: Company? = null
    var address: Address? = null
    var timestamp: Long = System.currentTimeMillis()
}

class Company {
    var companyId: String? = null
    var name: String? = null
    var email: String? = null
    var address: Address? = null
    var timestamp: Long? = null
}

class Address {
    var addressId: String? = null
    var label: String? = null
    var number: String? = null
    var street: String? = null
    var timestamp: Long = System.currentTimeMillis()
}

val db = nitrite {
    file = File(fileName)
    autoCommitBufferSize = 2048
    compress = true
    autoCompact = false
}

// create repository
val prospects = db.getRepository<Prospect>()

// create/get your object
val obj = Prospect()
...

// insert the object into the database
prospects.insert(obj)

// retrieve like
val cursor = prospects.find(Prospect::prospectId eq "xyz")

// or
val cursor = prospects.find("prospectId.company.address.number" eq 123)
```

2. You create 3 object repositories for `Prospects`, `Company` and `Address` separately and store the ids in place of reference. But there you have to make call to appropriate object repositories to fetch the actual object.

```kotlin
class Prospect {
    @Id
    var prospectId: String? = null
    var name: String? = null
    var lastName: String? = null
    var phone: String? = null
    var email: String? = null
    var companyId: String? = null
    var addressId: String? = null
    var timestamp: Long = System.currentTimeMillis()
}

class Company {
    @Id
    var companyId: String? = null
    var name: String? = null
    var email: String? = null
    var addressId: String? = null
    var timestamp: Long? = null
}

class Address {
    @Id
    var addressId: String? = null
    var label: String? = null
    var number: String? = null
    var street: String? = null
    var timestamp: Long = System.currentTimeMillis()
}

val db = nitrite {
    file = File(fileName)
    autoCommitBufferSize = 2048
    compress = true
    autoCompact = false
}

// create repositories
val prospects = db.getRepository<Prospect>()
val companies = db.getRepository<Company>()
val addresses = db.getRepository<Address>()

// create/get your objects
val pObj = Prospect()
val cObj = Company()
val aObj = Address()
...

// insert the object into the database
prospects.insert(pObj)
companies.insert(cObj)
addresses.insert(aObj)

// retrieve like
val p = prospects.find(Prospect::prospectId eq "xyz").firstOrNull()
val a = addresses.find(Address::addressId eq p.addressId)
```

Here is the full [documentation](https://www.dizitart.org/nitrite-database/) to help you, if you get stuck. I'll recommend you to use version 3.4.2 as it is production ready and stable.

Disclaimer: I am the developer of Nitrite database.

Answer (score 0):

> Room fails galactically! being a SQL and suffers doing it properly. Using room's @Embedded notation helps for one level of embedded document but the next level need to be using a TypeConverter. That is how SQL fails me.

Perhaps the following is along the lines of what you are looking for based upon the "Fake" data. This ignores the @DBRef's but instead has the Entities (tables) Address, Company and Prospect and has supportive POJO's CompanyWithAddress and (for want of a better name) ProspectWithCompanyWithAddressAndWithProspectAddress, these embedding the underlying respective entities using @Relation for the child objects.

So the Entities are :-

**Address**

```
@Entity /* This indicates that this is a table */
class Address {
    //@Id
    @PrimaryKey /* Room requires a Primary Key for a table */
    var addressId: String = ""
    var label: String? = null
    var number: String? = null
    var street: String? = null
    var timestamp: Long = /* nowToLongUTC() */ System.currentTimeMillis() /* used for convenience */
}
```

**Company**

```
@Entity(
    foreignKeys = [
        ForeignKey(
            entity = Address::class,
            parentColumns = ["addressId"],
            childColumns = ["addressRef"],
            /* You may or may not want onDelete and onUpdate actions */
            onDelete = ForeignKey.CASCADE,
            onUpdate = ForeignKey.CASCADE
            /* you may wish to refer to https://sqlite.org/foreignkeys.html */
        )
    ],
    indices = [
        Index("addressRef") /* Room will warn if a FK column is not indexed */
    ]
)
class Company {

    //@Id
    @PrimaryKey
    var companyId: String = ""
    var name: String? = null
    var email: String? = null

    //@DBRef
    //var address: Address? = null
    // Rather than de-normalise DB, waste space,
    // here we reference the address rather than include the address
    // the Foreign Key above adds a rule saying that the value of addressRef
    // MUST be a value that is in an addressId column in the address table
    // Foreign Keys are optional but recommended to enforce referential integrity
    // break the rule and an error occurs
    var addressRef: String? = null
    var timestamp: Long? = null
}
```

and **Prospect**

```
@Entity(
    foreignKeys = [
        ForeignKey(
            entity = Company::class,
            parentColumns = ["companyId"],
            childColumns = ["companyRef"],
            onDelete = ForeignKey.CASCADE,
            onUpdate = ForeignKey.CASCADE
        ),
        ForeignKey(
            entity = Address::class,
            parentColumns = ["addressId"],
            childColumns = ["prospectAddressRef"],
            onDelete = ForeignKey.CASCADE,
            onUpdate = ForeignKey.CASCADE
        )
    ],
    indices = [
        Index("companyRef"),
        Index("prospectAddressRef")
    ]
)
class Prospect {

    //@Id
    @PrimaryKey
    var prospectId: String = ""
    var name: String? = null
    var lastName: String? = null
    var phone: String? = null
    var email: String? = null

    //@DBRef
    var companyRef: String? = null

    //@DBRef
    @ColumnInfo(name = "prospectAddressRef") /* defines the column name in the table to avoid ambiguities */
    var addressRef: String? = null
    var timestamp: Long = /* nowToLongUTC() */ System.currentTimeMillis()
}
```

The POJO's :-

**CompanyWithAddress**

```
class CompanyWithAddress {
    @Embedded
    var company: Company? = null
    @Relation(
        entity = Address::class,
        parentColumn = "addressRef",
        entityColumn = "addressId"
    )
    var address: Address? = null
}
```

- So a company with it's address noting that the Address object is obtained via the addressRef that holds the addressId of the **related** address (no need for a TypeConverter)

and **ProspectWithCompanyWithAddressAndWithProspectAddress**

```
class ProspectWithCompanyWithAddressAndWithProspectAddress {
    @Embedded
    var prospect: Prospect? = null
    @Relation(
        entity = Company::class,
        parentColumn = "companyRef",
        entityColumn = "companyId"
    )
    var companyWithAddress: CompanyWithAddress? = null
    @Relation(
        entity = Address::class,
        parentColumn = "prospectAddressRef",
        entityColumn = "addressId"
    )
    var address: Address? = null
}
```

The Dao's for a demo of the above in a class named **AllDao**

```
@Dao
abstract class AllDao {

    @Insert
    abstract fun insert(address: Address): Long
    @Insert
    abstract fun insert(company: Company): Long
    @Insert
    abstract fun insert(prospect: Prospect): Long
    @Transaction
    @Query("SELECT * FROM prospect")
    abstract fun getALlFullProspects(): List<ProspectWithCompanyWithAddressAndWithProspectAddress>
}
```

- These allow the insertion into respective tables
- Note that due to the Foreign Keys addresses must be inserted before companies and prospects that use the address(es) and Companies must be inserted before the Prospect is inserted.

  - with Foreign Keys (which are optional) it wouldn't matter.

A pretty basic @Database **TheDatabase**

```
@Database(
    entities = [Address::class,Company::class,Prospect::class],
    version = 1
)
abstract class TheDatabase: RoomDatabase() {
    abstract fun getAllDao(): AllDao

    companion object {
        @Volatile
        private var instance: TheDatabase? = null
        fun getInstance(context: Context): TheDatabase {
            if (instance == null) {
                instance = Room.databaseBuilder(
                    context,
                    TheDatabase::class.java,
                    "thedatabase.db"
                )
                    .allowMainThreadQueries() /* for convenience/brevity of demo */
                    .build()
            }
            return instance as TheDatabase
        }
    }
}
```

Putting it all together in an Activity (run on the main thread for brevity/convenience) **MainActivity** :-

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    lateinit var db: TheDatabase
    lateinit var dao: AllDao
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        db = TheDatabase.getInstance(this)
        dao = db.getAllDao()

        val a1Id = "5cb2e9424274072ec4bb4199"
        val c1Id = "60847dc8ba7e6a4ae0fa5f93"
        val p1Id = "5cb2e9424274072ec4bb419c"

        var a1 = Address()
        a1.addressId = a1Id
        a1.label = "Home"
        a1.number = "1"
        a1.street = "MS Way"
        dao.insert(a1)

        var c1 = Company()
        c1.companyId = c1Id
        c1.email = "info@Microsoft.com"
        c1.name = "Microsoft"
        c1.addressRef = a1Id
        dao.insert(c1)

        var p1 = Prospect()
        p1.prospectId = p1Id
        p1.name = "Bill"
        p1.lastName = "Gates"
        p1.email = "gates.william@gmail.com"
        p1.phone = "0108101081"
        p1.companyRef = c1Id
        p1.addressRef = a1Id

        dao.insert(p1)

        /* Going to add a 2nd Prospect with a 2nd Company with separate addresses */ 
        val a2Id = "6cb2e9424274072ec4bb4199"
        val a3Id = "7cb2e9424274072ec4bb4199"
        val c2Id = "70847dc8ba7e6a4ae0fa5f93"
        val p2Id = "6cb2e9424274072ec4bb419c"

        /* change the initial address ready for the insert of the 2nd*/
        a1.addressId = a2Id
        a1.street = "Apple lane"
        a1.number = "33"
        a1.label = "Work"
        dao.insert(a1)

        /* change the 2nd address ready for the insert of the 3rd */
        a1.addressId = a3Id
        a1.label = "Holiday"
        a1.number = "111"
        a1.street = "Lazy Street"
        dao.insert(a1)

        /* Change the company and insert a new one */
        c1.companyId = c2Id
        c1.name = "Apple Inc"
        c1.email = "info@apple.inc"
        c1.addressRef = a2Id
        dao.insert(c1)

        /* Change the prospect and insert a new one */
        p1.addressRef = a3Id
        p1.companyRef = c2Id
        p1.prospectId = p2Id
        dao.insert(p1)


        /* Now the data has been added extract it and output the extracted to the log*/
        var TAG = "PROSPECTINFO"
        for(p: ProspectWithCompanyWithAddressAndWithProspectAddress in dao.getALlFullProspects()) {
            Log.d(TAG,
                "Prospect: Name = ${p.prospect!!.name}, ${p.prospect!!.lastName} Phone is ${p.prospect!!.phone}" +
                        "\n\tCompany is ${p.companyWithAddress!!.company!!.name} " +
                        "\n\t\tCompany Address is ${p.companyWithAddress!!.address!!.number} ${p.companyWithAddress!!.address!!.street}" +
                        "\n\tProspect Address is ${p.address!!.number} ${p!!.address!!.street}"
            )
        }
    }
}
```

**Result**

The log when the above is run (designed to just run the once, running a second time would result in UNIQIUE conflicts) :-

```
D/PROSPECTINFO: Prospect: Name = Bill, Gates Phone is 0108101081
        Company is Microsoft 
            Company Address is 1 MS Way
        Prospect Address is 1 MS Way
D/PROSPECTINFO: Prospect: Name = Bill, Gates Phone is 0108101081
        Company is Apple Inc 
            Company Address is 33 Apple lane
        Prospect Address is 111 Lazy Street
```

Via App Inspector the database is:-

The Address table :-

[image]

The Company table :-

[image]

- timestamps are NULL as they weren't set (as per your original code)

The Prospect table :-

[image]

- Name/Last Name etc are the same values as these weren't changed. Importantly though the companyRef and  prospectAddressRef values reference the respective companies/addresses.

Comment: Currently I am doing it this way, It's just that SQL, like linear programming cannot describe the reality we live in therefore Object Orientation came for programming But SQL did not change ! However Document based DB's works much better, Android misses such an choice. - Good work